# Pixel values change after clipping a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, pixel

I'm trying to evaluate mean temperatures for the distribution area of European fish species. Therefore, I downloaded the E-OBS data set for mean annual temperature in Europe (0.25 deg. reg., "TG"), loaded it into QGIS and clipped the raster using a polygon shape as a mask. 
I did not alter the projection, but I added the command 
`--config GDALWARP_IGNORE_BAD_CUTLINE YES` 
to the console: [image: Clipping window]
After that, I used the value tool to extract pixel values for random locations of the newly clipped layer and noticed, that strongly deviate from the original data. Unfortunately, I can't post more that 2 links here, but the original data is in °C values and the clipped layer has values in the magnitude of plus-minus several hundreds.

Is there an obvious flaw in my workflow I'm not seeing?

edit: Text fraction of the Layer obtained from Layer properties->Metadata->Properties:

> D:/GoogleDrive/Sonstiges/GIS/tg_0.25deg_reg_1950-1964_v15.0.nc/tg_0.25deg_reg_1950-1964_v15.0.nc
>   latitude#long_name=Latitude values
>   latitude#standard_name=latitude
>   latitude#units=degrees_north
>   longitude#long_name=Longitude values
>   longitude#standard_name=longitude
>   longitude#units=degrees_east
>   NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.4
>   NC_GLOBAL#Ensembles_ECAD=15.0
>   NC_GLOBAL#history=Wed May 31 15:20:56 2017: ncks -a -d time,0,5478 tg_0.25deg_regular_1.nc tg_0.25deg_reg_1950-1964_v15.0.nc Wed May 31 15:19:16 2017: ncks -a --mk_rec_dmn time tg_0.25deg_regular.nc tg_0.25deg_regular_1.nc
>   NC_GLOBAL#NCO="4.6.2"
>   NC_GLOBAL#References=http://www.ecad.eu\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/ensembles.php\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/Haylock_et_al_2008.pdf
>   NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time}
>   NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={5479,4}
>   NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,[...]

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/252969/edit) and provide either `gdalinfo` output for the input raster or (in QGIS) the text in Layer properties->Metadata->Properties.

Comment: Is there a specific part of the text you're interested in? The entire length is extremely long.

Comment: I'm looking for a scale factor in the NC metadata, but also the basic raster properties. Is there a direct link to the original dataset /metadata etc?

Comment: there is: http://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php
It is the 0.25 deg. regular grid, Version 15.0, 1950-1964, TG file.

Comment: Are the pixels shifted relative to the original dataset?

Comment: To be honest; I wouldn't even know how to investigate that..
Apologies, I'm a GIS beginner.